# How can I insert rows in HP Vertica using SQLWorkbench/J?

Tags: sql, vertica, sql-workbench-j

How can I insert rows in HP Vertica using SQLWorkbench/J?

I have tried clicking "Insert a new row after the highlighted row." button but as soon as I click on the next cell following the new cell of the new row after inputting data, the inputted data is gone.

Please help.

Comment: I have used SQL Workbench/J against a Vertica database and edited result sets. Do your tables have a primary key?

Comment: yes, they have. i have tried clicking "Insert a new row after the highlighted row." but my newly added data did not reflect. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried DB Visualizer?

Comment: No, I haven't. I need to check first with SQL Workbench/J.

Comment: Try COMMIT; after your insert.

Comment: If it's a commit issue, the GUI tool may not be auto committing. You may want to  `\set AUTOCOMMIT 'on'`.

Comment: You probably get more help if you post in the SQL Workbench/J forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sql-workbench

Comment: @fenix i think it's not a commit issue. every time i insert a new row and just by clicking on a cell in this row, the data is reset.

Comment: Did you try to Commit?

Comment: @fenix I can't commit yet because I could not complete a row. As i've said, every time i go to another cell in the new row, my previously inputted data in previous cell is automatically wiped out.

Comment: My last resort is to use COPY command in HP Vertica.

Comment: Ok, just check is AutoCommit is on (Kermit advice). It's in your connections settings

Comment: @fenix I also tried that but unfortunately, it did not work. :(